# How can I hide/show an HTML element created dynamically after in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a program that shows 2 types of price. If the user is registered, they will see the normal price and the discount; if the user is not registered, they will see *only* the normal price. So I would like to hide the discounted one in this case.

```
string resumen = "<div id='coliz'>";

resumen += "<img src='img/" + p.getNombre().ToLower().Replace(" ", "_") + "_" + p.getColor().ToLower().Replace(" ", "_") + ".png'  alt=''/>" +
"<div class='presupuesto'>" +
"<div id=pvp runat='server'><h2>PVP</h2><h2 class='precio' id='precio' data-val='" + p.getPrecio() + "'>" + String.Format("{0:C}", p.getPrecio()) + "</h2></div>" +
"<div id=pvd runat='server'><h2>PVD</h2><h2 class='precio' id='preciopvd' data-val='" + p.getPrecio() + "'>" + String.Format("{0:C}", p.getPrecio()) + "</h2></div>" +
"<ul class='caracteristicas'>";
```

I set the prices dynamically from the database creating the HTML content

```
<div id="contenido">
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <%=_resumen %>
</div>
```

My main idea was make a query to the database and get the value of the discount, then act in function:

```
_resumen = setResumen();
_custom = setCustomization();
descuento = db.isReseller(AppleCTO.CodigoCliente);
HiddenDescuento.Value = descuento.ToString();
```

This code is on the `Page_Load`.

My problem is: I can't or I don't know how to control these elements created dynamically after in C# on the `Page_Load`. Or maybe I can pass the date with the HiddenField and perform the actions with `jQuery`.

I tried the `jQuery`:

```
var descuento = $('#HiddenDescuento').val();
// VISIBILIDAD DEL PVD
if (descuento == 0) {
    $("#preciopvd").hide()
}
// VISIBILIDAD DEL PVD
```

What are different solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know full structure of your program, I can suggest something as below.
create HTML Block and make it hidden like `style='display:none;'`

**Use JQuery**
to hide, instead of

```
if (descuento == 0) {
  $("#preciopvd").hide()
}
```

use this,

```
if (descuento == 0) {
    $("#preciopvd").css("display","none");
}
```

and to show,

```
if (descuento == 0) {
    $("#preciopvd").css("display","block");
}
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Finally i solved the issue with a less optimal solution. I just separated the function of create the content from the DB in two different functions and the calling of one of each depends on the query result of the registered user! Thanks for your edit and response